# how to get each rows as dictionary and update in a new column with the dictionary respectively

Tags: kdb

We have a table called "tab" which contains approximately 1000 rows with the following columns and data. Now, I would like to add a new column called "dict_text" that will store a dictionary for each row in the table.

```
n: 100;  // Number of rows in the table
tab:([] date: .z.d - n?30; ranks: n?100; sym: n?`MSFT`AAPL`GOOG; price: "f"$n?100.5; recv_time: n?10:00:00.000 + n?10000000; is_active: "b"$n?1 0);

date    ranks   sym price   recv_time   is_active
2023-05-02  81  GOOG    10.981034816592 11:52:06.125    1b
2023-05-02  67  AAPL    24.013786250841804  10:05:21.388    0b
2023-05-10  10  AAPL    33.92489333683625   10:25:47.734    1b
2023-05-16  55  MSFT    20.40686718339566   10:05:21.388    1b
2023-05-13  99  GOOG    70.15338694362435   10:31:17.210    1b
2023-05-05  36  GOOG    53.519611683441326  10:37:00.064    1b
2023-04-23  10  MSFT    56.23836425843183   10:34:22.771    1b
2023-05-06  21  AAPL    62.24877665319946   12:25:38.810    1b
2023-05-04  39  MSFT    35.28165666293353   10:23:23.324    0b
2023-05-15  53  AAPL    65.13382041512523   11:41:54.982    0b
```

Final output shall look like below

```
date      ranks  sym        price           recv_time   is_active    dict_text
2023-05-02  81  GOOG    10.981034816592     11:52:06.125    1b       `date`ranks`sym`price`recv_time`is_active!(2023-05-02;81;`GOOG;10.981034816592;11:52:06.125;1b)
2023-05-02  67  AAPL    24.013786250841804  10:05:21.388    0b       `date`ranks`sym`price`recv_time`is_active!(2023-05-02;67;`AAPL;24.013786250841804;10:05:21.388;0b)
2023-05-10  10  AAPL    33.92489333683625   10:25:47.734    1b       `date`ranks`sym`price`recv_time`is_active!(2023-05-10;10;`AAPL;33.92489333683625;10:25:47.734;1b)
2023-05-16  55  MSFT    20.40686718339566   10:05:21.388    1b       `date`ranks`sym`price`recv_time`is_active!(2023-05-16;55;`MSFT;20.40686718339566;10:05:21.388;1b)
2023-05-13  99  GOOG    70.15338694362435   10:31:17.210    1b       `date`ranks`sym`price`recv_time`is_active!(2023-05-13;99;`GOOG;70.15338694362435;10:31:17.210;1b)
2023-05-05  36  GOOG    53.519611683441326  10:37:00.064    1b       `date`ranks`sym`price`recv_time`is_active!(2023-05-05;36;`GOOG;53.519611683441326;10:37:00.064;1b)
2023-04-23  10  MSFT    56.23836425843183   10:34:22.771    1b       `date`ranks`sym`price`recv_time`is_active!(2023-04-23;10;`MSFT;56.23836425843183;10:34:22.771;1b)
2023-05-06  21  AAPL    62.24877665319946   12:25:38.810    1b       `date`ranks`sym`price`recv_time`is_active!(2023-05-06;21;`AAPL;62.248776653199;12:25:38.810;1b)
2023-05-04  39  MSFT    35.28165666293353   10:23:23.324    0b       `date`ranks`sym`price`recv_time`is_active!(2023-05-04;39;`MSFT;35.28165666293346;10:23:23.324;0b)
2023-05-15  53  AAPL    65.13382041512523   11:41:54.982    0b       `date`ranks`sym`price`recv_time`is_active!(2023-05-15;53;`AAPL;65.13382041512523;11:41:54.982;0b)
```

Comment: Is this really programming related?

Comment: I'm curious why you would want to do this? Seems like unnecessary duplication when each row is a dictionary anyway. Of course I have no idea what your use case is.

Comment: I have a use case where from one tab1 we need few cols and rest cols i need as ref purpose to pub to another tab2 with different schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other answers seem to have complicated this a little, I think you can just do:

```
update dict_text:tab from tab
```

You can do this because tab is, by definition, already a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

You can do following

```
tab[`dict_text]: {x} each tab;
tab
```

`{x} each`  iterates through every row and converts it to required dictionary

Comment: Don't need to iterate ``tab[`dict_text]:tab`` works the same

Answer (score 1):

```
update dict_text:tab@i from tab
```

Comment: Can simplify further to just `update dict_text:tab from tab`